# Why can't my webserver write (PERMISSIONS ISSUE)

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I have this filesystem

```
$ ls -la /var/www/myapp/api/project/files/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 Jun 17 14:28 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 me me 4096 Jun 17 14:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me 4096 Jun 17 14:28 cache
```

I have added `www-data` to my group (`sudo usermod -a -G me www-data`)

```
$ getent group me
me:x:1005:www-data
```

And my web server is telling me

> Error: Can not create directory
>   /var/www/myapp/api/project/files/cache/users

Why is my web server, running as `www-data`, unable to write when permissions are set as `775`?

Comment: Did you restart apache so that the www-data user would see the new group membership?

Comment: @ivanivan yes I did, multiple times just to be sure.

Comment: Do you knew what user and group the server is started as. Is it started as a normal user, so gets all of the groups? You are correct in saying that I miss-understood in my previous answer. I added a new answer. It come down to the same advice, but for a different reason

Comment: Are you sure `www-data` has access (`+x`). to any component, starting with `/var`? (maybe obvious, but always useful to double check). Try increasing your webserver logging so that you get more information. Try manually to switch to `www-data` (sudo/su) and create the directory you may get better error message...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I just checked, every node starting from `var` has `5` as global permissions which is `rx`. Oddly enough, today it's working without me touching anything overnight..

Answer (score 1):

Making it a member of your group is not a good idea. This way it can read and write all of you files. Some external entity may discover a way to trick it into reading or writing your files.

Instead give it permission no read/write the directory. Change the group of the web-server directory `/var/www/myapp/api/project/files/cache/`.

Comment: I can easily fix the problem by changing the ownership of the node, my question is why it's not working the way it is, as it should be. I'm not worried about the webserver having access to my home directory because this machine is solely made to serve this website, but that's outside of the scope of the question.